# Py How to save an specific argument of the input

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to do is saving the 2th argument of an single input to an specific variable to parse it on an argument in my another function so that my function works.

```
import sys
import requests
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()



def test(url):
    bb = requests.get(url)
    if bb.status == 200:
        bb = "Success"
    else:
        bb = False
    print(bb)

def main():
    x = input("Choose: ")

    dd = parser.add_argument(x)
    if x == "check-status " + dd.dest:
        test(dd) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So here it also saves the "check-status". But I do want that it only saves the 2th argument of input x in dd.dest.

Can someone help. I tried researching a lot on internet but couldn't find an solution.

Comment: can you refrase your question, I don't understand what the problem is and I don't understand what you want to do.
may be give us an exaple of what you do and the output vs the output you actullay want

Comment: So when user types check-status site.com then only the 2th argument site.com will go into test function parsed as argument not the check-status

Comment: I don't understand why you are using parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a little:

```
import requests

def test(url):
    bb = requests.get(url)
    if bb.status_code == 200: <--this is changed to status_code
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Failed")
    

def main():
    x = input("Choose: ")
   
    if "check-status " in x:
        test(x.replace("check-status","").strip()) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```